# Numpy rounds in a different way than python

Tags: python, numpy, rounding-error, rounding

The code

```
import numpy as np
a = 5.92270987499999979065
print(round(a, 8))
print(round(np.float64(a), 8))
```

gives

```
5.92270987
5.92270988
```

Any idea why?

Found nothing relevant in numpy sources.

**Update:**
I know that the proper way to deal with this problem is to construct programs in such a way that this difference is irrelevant. Which I do. I stumbled into it in regression testing.

**Update2:**
Regarding the @VikasDamodar comment. One shouldn't trust the `repr()` function:

```
>>> np.float64(5.92270987499999979065)
5.922709875
>>> '%.20f' % np.float64(5.92270987499999979065)
'5.92270987499999979065'
```

**Update3:**
Tested on python3.6.0 x32, numpy 1.14.0, win64. Also on python3.6.4 x64, numpy 1.14.0, debian.

**Update4:**
Just to be sure:

```
import numpy as np
a = 5.92270987499999979065
print('%.20f' % round(a, 8))
print('%.20f' % round(np.float64(a), 8))

5.92270987000000026512
5.92270988000000020435
```

**Update5:**
The following code demonstrates on which stage the difference takes place without using `str`:

```
>>> np.float64(a) - 5.922709874
1.000000082740371e-09
>>> a - 5.922709874
1.000000082740371e-09
>>> round(np.float64(a), 8) - 5.922709874
6.000000496442226e-09
>>> round(a, 8) - 5.922709874
-3.999999442783064e-09
```

Clearly, before applying 'round' they were the same number.

**Update6:**
In contrast to @user2357112's answer, `np.round` is roughly 4 times slower than round:

```
%%timeit a = 5.92270987499999979065
round(a, 8)

1.18 µs ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)  

%%timeit a = np.float64(5.92270987499999979065)
round(a, 8)

4.05 µs ± 43.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Also in my opinion `np.round` did a better job rounding to the nearest even than builtin `round`: originally I got this 5.92270987499999979065 number through dividing 11.84541975 by two.

Comment: PS I know that `round(0.5)==0` and `round(1.5)==2`.

Comment: Wow. Indeed `round(0.5) == 0`. Why is that? That seems to be a severe bug!

Comment: @mrCarnivore `round(0.5)==0` is by design in most computer languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Comment: @mrCarnivore It is round to nearest even..not a bug..but still weird..

Comment: Then my knowledge of numerics has faded since university... I did not know that rounding to the nearest even is by design. Good to know, though! Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly enough, for the 9th digit they round the same.. This seems to lie in the rounding policy of numpys round (np.round(a,8) also rounds up to 8) I guess?

Comment: The problem with `np.float64(a)` wich will return `5.922709875` , So when `np` rounds the number it gives correct o/p.

Comment: @VikasDamodar see update2 above

Comment: Which Python arch/version/OS? It gives the same results here in Python 2.7.14 win32.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins its not number anymore, its become `str`

Comment: @VikasDamodar. Not only it has become `str`, it became `str` with 20 digits of precision.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev see update3 above

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins `round(np.float(a), 8)` gives the same result, Thats why I told may be this issue or bug what ever is with `float64`

Comment: Might be interesting: `np.float64.__round__ == np.float32.__round__` and `np.float.__round__ == float.__round__` **but** `np.float64.__round__ != float.__round__`! Thus, `round(a)` and `round(np.float64(a))` are executing different code.

Comment: @VikasDamodar see Update4 above

Comment: @Amadan This is sorted of expected for they are returning different types of variables. You would neither expect native python `round` to return `np.float64`, nor `np.round` to return a native `float`

Comment: Yes. Just saying, you probably want to see exactly what is numpy's round (i.e. `np.generic.__round__`) and what it does differently than Python's native `float.__round__`. Without looking at the source, seems like numpy's `round` doesn't detect the border correctly.

Comment: Interesting observation is that string formatting works correctly. `'%.8f' % np.float64(5.92270987499999979065)` returns `'5.92270987'`. It is likely a bug in numpy's `round()` functionality.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins you are just making a string with 20 precision from your first answer and you already know both returns diffrent So when you tries to make str that returned value how it will be same, and its not a float value it is str

Comment: @VikasDamodar see Update5 above. You could post your idea as a separate answer, because the question becomes cluttered.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins they are not the same , check here : https://repl.it/repls/SubstantialHummingFrenchbulldog

Comment: Looking at your Update 4, it appears that numpy's `round()` is returning the nearest binary value to the desired rounded value even though that nearest value may display differently when output in decimal.

Comment: This is not a solution or explanation, but what about replacing `round()` with `np.around()`? That way at least all your assumptions are `numpy` assumptions.

Comment: @casevh you all are forgetting that the underlying data is encoded in binary, at least the float64. This way, on top of the rounding in the numerical library another rounding is done when printing a number with decimals. The answer from user2357112 reflects this. The displayed difference most likely will be larger than when comparing the binary representation.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis not sure what exactly do you suggest to replace and what assumptions do you mean. Could you post this suggestion as an answer, please?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins. all I mean is, trivially, `np.around(a, 8) == np.around(np.float64(a), 8)`.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis This is undoubledly true but I'm not really sure it might prove. When you call `round(np.float64(a))` it calls `float64.__round__` which is pretty the same thing what `np.around` does internally.

Answer (score 5):

[`float.__round__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/floatobject.c#L905) takes special care to produce correctly-rounded results, using a correctly-rounded double-to-string algorithm.

NumPy does not. The [NumPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) mention that

> Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard [R9] and **errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten**.

This is faster, but produces more rounding error. It leads to errors like what you've observed, as well as errors where numbers even more unambiguously below the cutoff still get rounded up:

```
>>> x = 0.33499999999999996
>>> x
0.33499999999999996
>>> x < 0.335
True
>>> x < Decimal('0.335')
True
>>> x < 0.67/2
True
>>> round(x, 2)
0.33
>>> numpy.round(x, 2)
0.34000000000000002
```

---

You're getting a slower time for NumPy's rounding, but that doesn't have anything to do with which rounding algorithm is slower. Any time comparison between NumPy and regular Python math will boil down to the fact that NumPy is optimized for whole-array operations. Doing math on single NumPy scalars has a lot of overhead, but rounding an entire array with `numpy.round` easily beats rounding a list of floats with `round`:

```
In [6]: import numpy

In [7]: l = [i/7 for i in range(100)]

In [8]: a = numpy.array(l)

In [9]: %timeit [round(x, 1) for x in l]
59.6 µs ± 408 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit numpy.round(a, 1)
5.27 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As for which one is more accurate, that's definitely `float.__round__`. Your number is closer to 5.92270987 than to 5.92270988, and it's round-*ties*-to-even, not round-everything-to-even. There's no tie here.

Comment: This sounds convincing, but in this particular example numpy's result looks more correct to me. Do you have a link to read more about the double-to-string algorithm?

Comment: The conversions between double and string are implemented in [`Python/dtoa.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/dtoa.c), based on [David Gay's `dtoa.c`](http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But in my particular case the "correct" result is 5.92270988 because originally I got this number through dividing 11.84541975 by 2. You think numpy got this correct result by mistake?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: The fact that you got your number by dividing 11.84541975 by 2 doesn't make 5.92270988 correct. I don't see why you would think that. The fact that NumPy's rounding error happens to match your unusual expectations is a fluke.

Comment: Computer is made to solve real-world problems. So are computer languages. If I take a half of 33 cents I want to get 16 cents, not `round(0.33/2,2)==0.17`. Yes, Decimal type is better fitted to solving this problem. But it is slower than numpy - I can't afford losing those milliseconds. I need to get the same result in numpy. It looks as though the optimal solution would be `round(0.33*100)/100` or its 1e8 equivalent in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643563/237105) below. If effectively works around this difference in rounding algorithms and allows for regression testing.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: You're setting yourself up for problems with code like that; you looked at a fluke of rounding error that happened to match your intuition once, and you're counting on it to keep matching your intuition with further inputs. It won't.

Comment: If you happen to read numpy sources [multiarray/calculation.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c), you'll see that it is not a fluke but instead it is exactly what is described in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643563/237105) below and what I need in my particular situation. And it is a better solution than your 'correctly-rounded double-to-string' when applied to real-world cases.

Comment: Thank you for our answer, it was useful for me, but I'll re-accept my own answer as a more correct one tomorrow (SO doesn't allow to do it today).

Comment: I would dispute _"This is faster, but less correct."_ comment. It really depends on the problem which approach is "more correct".

Comment: @AGNGazer: [Which of these results for round(0.055, 2) do you consider more correct?](https://ideone.com/fY8yZB) I have a hard time thinking of any problem where NumPy's 0.059999999999999998 is more correct than Python's 0.06.

Comment: Are we talking about inexact representation of floating numbers or about rounding procedure? Is `numpy`'s result due to the inexact representation of 0.6? Can Python *exactly* represent 0.6?

Comment: By the way, have you tried `float(np.round(0.055, 2))`?

Comment: Don't waste your time thinking on something which does not exist. Those two are just the same number >>> f'{round(0.055, 2):.20f}' '0.05999999999999999778' >>> f'{np.round(0.055, 2):.20f}' '0.05999999999999999778' It's just about numpy's `repr()` being more honest than float's.

Comment: @AGNGazer: bleh, that's what I get for trying to reproduce the example from memory - 0.055 is the wrong input

Comment: Looking at the examples not-from-memory, the examples I was thinking of were for a different sequence of operations, so I don't have anything that'd be likely to change your mind.

Comment: user2357112, @AGNGazer plz check my [yet another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48659524/237105) answer - the first one got downvoted too much.

Answer (score 0):

And yes, yet another way to deal with such things is to use Decimal which is not *that* slow in python3:

```
%%timeit d = D('11.84541975'); q = D('0.00000001')
(d/2).quantize(q)

485 ns ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

**tldr**

Builtin `round` and `numpy.round` use different algorithms for rounding. Their results are identical for most numbers, but substantially different for some corner cases.

Both are good for certain uses.

`round` is faster for scalars, `np.round` is faster for arrays.

**explanation**

•  Builtin `round` uses a straightforward approach of checking the decimal digit right after the requested one. It rounds 4 downwards no matter what happens to be after (even if it is ...499999), and rounds 5 to the nearest even unless it has a single 1 thereafter (eg ...500001), in which case it rounds up.

•  `np.round` multiplies the number to the requested the power of 10, rounds to the nearest int by ordinary rules, then divides back by the same power of 10.

It gives more predictable results for cases like 0.33/2:

```
>>> 0.33/2
0.165
>>> round(0.33/2, 2)
0.17
>>> np.round(0.33/2, 2)
0.16
```

Here 0.165 should've been rounded to the nearest even which is 0.16.

**Update:**
Yet it suffers from round-off errors for cases like 1.09/2 (as noted by Mark Dickinson in the comment):

```
>>> 1.09/2
0.545
>>> round(1.09/2, 2)
0.55
>>> np.round(1.09/2, 2)
0.55
```

The only workaround I could think of is

```
>>> round(round(1.09*100)/2)/100
0.54
```

which works but is far from being universal.

Comment: "for applications dealing with money" - oh geeze you're using this for *money*? Binary floating point is absolutely not the right tool for working with money.

Comment: `np.round` _doesn't_ try to guess what the user wanted. It just happens that the algorithm it uses tends to produce what looks like the correct result more often than Python's correctly-rounded algorithm does. But not always: for example, `np.round(0.545, 2)` will give `0.55`, not `0.54`, and `np.round(0.575, 2)` will give `0.57` rather than `0.58`.

Comment: @user2357112 I addressed this issue in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48643809/edit) below. Yes, Decimal type is way better suited when dealing with money. But it is slower than numpy. And I'm dealing with arrays. Also pandas doesn't work with Decimal.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, that's a problem. The best thing I could think of is `round((round(1.09*100)/2))/100 == 0.54`.

Comment: Removed the questionable parts from the answer.

Comment: @user2357112 for cryptomoney, so it is not that bad ;)

Answer (score -2):

In my particular case a pretty straightforward way of working around the difference between those two functions to get consistent results is through multiplying and dividing.

For my application it seems to be working better than native `round` giving the same result as `np.round`:

```
'%.20f' % (round(a*1e8)/1e8)
'5.92270988000000020435'
'%.20f' % (round(np.float64(a)*1e8)/1e8)
'5.92270988000000020435'
```

**Update**
Thanks to @user2357112 I found out that it is exactly what happens in `np.round` internally ([multiarray/calculation.c#L665](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L665)), so unless you're cross-testing your results between numpy and native python it's safe just to use the numpy version of round without those extra divisions and multiplications on python level.

**Update2**
When dealing with scalars, this method of division&multiplication on python level is somewhat (~30%) slower than native `round` but significantly faster (~3 times) than `np.round` (giving the same result as `np.round`):

```
%%timeit c = 11.84541975
round(c/2)
349 ns ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit c = 11.84541975
round(c*1e8/2)/1e8
519 ns ± 13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit c = np.float64(11.84541975)
round(c/2)
1.67 µs ± 20.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit c = np.float64(11.84541975)
round(c*1e8/2)/1e8
2.01 µs ± 37.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Update3**
Python's builtin `round` uses a straightforward approach which engages 'round-to-even' rule only for exactly representable dyadic rationals, like 0.375 (which is an integer divided by an exact power of two), thus effectively substituting this rule for all other numbers with 'round the tie number which happens to have 49999 representation down and happens to end with 50001 up'. I'm not really sure if this algorithm is better or worse, but definitely it is less suitable for checking manually.

Comment: Round-to-even doesn't only kick in for negative powers of 2 with `float.__round__`; it kicks in for exactly representable dyadic rationals, like `0.375`.